# How to start Windows Phone application development

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is it enough to start with Visual Studio 2008.Need any additional SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MSDN "phone" portal features a "Get the tools" section:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ff380145

(Well, at least for the UK MSDN).  In summary:

> Clicking this button installs:
>
> - Visual Studio 2010 Express
> - XNA Game Studio 4.0
> - Windows Phone Emulator
> - Microsoft Expression Blend for Windows Phone
> - Platforms: Silverlight, .NET Framework 4.0

It's a web installer, and you need VS 2010 - anything older is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

Try and understand these two points

1) If you machine doesnt have Visual Studio 2010 installed then you can directly download the WP CTP tools from create.msdn.com and install it. It Would install Visual Studio Express for Windows Phone

2)If you have Visual Studio 2010 installed, then try installing Visual Studio SP1 and then WP SDK 7.1.1(Mango)

The First method would restrict you to create Just only WP apps using Visual studio whereas the second method would give you the complete VS package and tools

Answer (score 1):

No, you need Visual Studio 2010. You can get all the tools and SDKs that you need from the App Hub at http://create.msdn.com/en-us/resources/downloads

Comment: Is it possible to develop mobile app with Visual Studio 2010 alone.? or need any additional SDK?

Comment: You need Visual Studio 2010 and the Windows Phone SDK, which is all part of the same download from the link I gave before. You don't need anything else.